# PHP variable scope: passing external objects to a class

Tags: php, class, pdo, scope

I'm defining models that share a common database. However, I'm having trouble passing a PDO object via `require_once()`. I'm getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object...
```

I'm guessing this is just a scope issue. I tried declaring `$database` as a `global` in both files but that didn't seem to work. Any ideas?

**common.php**

```
$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'database';
$username = 'user';
$password = 'pass';

$database = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
```

**product.php**

```
require_once('common.php');

class Product {

  function fetch_from_category($category) {
    $query = $database->prepare('SELECT * FROM product WHERE product.category = ?');
    $query->execute($category);
    return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }

}
```

Comment: `$database` is defined outside the class; and, similar to normal functions, you can't see the variable inside a class. Either pass it to the class as MrCode suggested or set it as global ( not recommended though ) as Rawkode suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a scope issue, `$database` is not defined inside `Product::fetch_from_category`. You should pass it into the object when instantiating it:

```
class Product {

  protected $database;

  public function __construct(PDO $database) {
      $this->database = $database;
  }

  public function fetch_from_category($category) {
      $query = $this->database->prepare('SELECT * FROM product WHERE product.category = ?');
      $query->execute($category);
      return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }

}
```

...

```
require_once 'common.php';
require_once 'product.php';

$product = new Product($database);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass `$database` to the class, then store it as a property and access with `$this->database`:

```
class Product {

  protected $database;

  public function setDb($db)
  {
      $this->database = $db;
  }

  function fetch_from_category($category) {
    $query = $this->database->prepare('SELECT * FROM product WHERE product.category = ?');
    $query->execute($category);
    return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }

}

$p = new Product();
$p->setDb($database);
```